# How to set background for <div> only part of the picture?

Tags: html, css

My image is divided as after image below. I want to set background for `div` at D position. How can I do that?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: please post your code or fiddle then we can help you.

Comment: welcome to SO, show us your current CSS and HTML and your attempt to position the image. Have you tried `background-position`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say it's an image, to which the answer would be, just use MS Paint to change the colour of that part. But the rest of your post speaks about <div>s, so which one is it? If the latter, apply `background-color`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes. My picture is divided to 4 a part of as: A, B, C, D. When I set background for div tag by class, I want to get position at D of my picture.

Answer (score 0):

I prepare some code for You, which is doing this. Its simple, You only must set the value of position to be good for You. Here is some example:

> The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0 0. Units can be pixels (0px 0px) or any other CSS units. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. You can mix % and positions

```css
.example{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAMmivmfGLDnoIppxvhs-wNrPVXspQW8KHzvVXXFlBHauDL-ZpQQ');    
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 70% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div class="example">
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```